# Android java.lang.nullpointerexception read file

Tags: java, android

other ways to read the file.??
Why not read ..?
text in the read always "**java.lang.nullpointerexception**".

```
public class TopRatedFragment extends Fragment {
private static final String FILENAME = "data.data";
private Context context;
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.setting, container, false);
    EditText message = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mesaage);
    read(rootView);
    return rootView;
}
   public void read(View view){
       EditText message = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.mesaage);
          try{
             FileInputStream fin = context.openFileInput(FILENAME);
             int c;
             String temp="";
             while( (c = fin.read()) != -1){
                 temp = temp + Character.toString((char)c);
              }
                  //Read Text
             message.setText(temp, BufferType.EDITABLE);
          }catch(Exception e){
                  //read Eroor
              message.setText(e.toString(), BufferType.EDITABLE);
          }
    }


}
```

who can help me.??

Comment: everyone helps you..no problem...i saw 1 problem i.e your context is not initialized or assigned yet.. check it..

Comment: Thanks @Ranjit...[ Solved ],,,, with "context = getActivity(); "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a simple solution for you..
Do some thing like:

```
//First get your current context then use it...
context = getActivity();
FileInputStream fin = context.openFileInput(FILENAME);
```

Comment: Thanks @Ranjit...[ Solved ],,,, with "context = getActivity(); "

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

Use `EditText message` as **Global** don't use `EditText message = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.mesaage);` like below

```
EditText message;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.setting, container, false);
    message = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mesaage);
    read(rootView);
    return rootView;
}
   public void read(View view){
          try{
             FileInputStream fin = context.openFileInput(FILENAME);
             int c;
             String temp="";
             while( (c = fin.read()) != -1){
                 temp = temp + Character.toString((char)c);
              }
                  //Read Text
             message.setText(temp, BufferType.EDITABLE);
          }catch(Exception e){
                  //read Eroor
              message.setText(e.toString(), BufferType.EDITABLE);
          }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for answered, but this is not a solution. Still the same Error "java.lang.nullpointerexception".
In my opinion, It is located in code a try { _bla_bla_ }. but I do not know why can not read.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(new File(FILENAME));
```